# Find a shape within a shape with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to find a shape within a shape using a python. I am using CV2 package and follow Detect_Shape tutorial code. It goes like this

**detect_shapes.py**

```
   # import the necessary packages
from shapedetector import ShapeDetector
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# load the image and resize it to a smaller factor so that
# the shapes can be approximated better
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
cv2.bitwise_not ( image, image );
resized = imutils.resize(image, width=300)
ratio = image.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])

# convert the resized image to grayscale, blur it slightly,
# and threshold it
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# find contours in the thresholded image and initialize the
# shape detector
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
sd = ShapeDetector()
# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # compute the center of the contour, then detect the name of the
    # shape using only the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
    cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
    shape = sd.detect(c)

    # multiply the contour (x, y)-coordinates by the resize ratio,
    # then draw the contours and the name of the shape on the image
    c = c.astype("float")
    c *= ratio
    c = c.astype("int")
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, shape, (cX, cY), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**shapedetector.py**

```
# import the necessary packages
import cv2

class ShapeDetector:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def detect(self, c):
        # initialize the shape name and approximate the contour
        shape = "unidentified"
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
        # if the shape is a triangle, it will have 3 vertices
        if len(approx) == 3:
            shape = "triangle"

        # if the shape has 4 vertices, it is either a square or
        # a rectangle
        elif len(approx) == 4:
            # compute the bounding box of the contour and use the
            # bounding box to compute the aspect ratio
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            ar = w / float(h)

            # a square will have an aspect ratio that is approximately
            # equal to one, otherwise, the shape is a rectangle
            shape = "square" if ar >= 0.95 and ar <= 1.05 else "rectangle"

        # if the shape is a pentagon, it will have 5 vertices
        elif len(approx) == 5:
            shape = "pentagon"

        # otherwise, we assume the shape is a circle
        else:
            shape = "circle"

        # return the name of the shape
        return shape
```

The image I am running the code on looks like this [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h07Uc.png) . For now I am trying to get the code to mark all the shapes in the pictures but ultimately I need it to detect shapes like circle within square with a line in a middle.

I tried inverting the colors but it does not see anything in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

There is one option that works but not so efficent:
after find the contours in the image you can create another image from each contour you find and then use `cv2.findContour` function with the new image from the contour